# Binding the Key in <object property="{StaticResource key}" .../> to a value

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, staticresource

In WPF, is it possible to bind the key in "{StaticResource key}"to a variable.

For example. I have a variable **ExecutionState** with the states **Active** and **Completed**.

In my ResourceDictionary I have

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="Active">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="Completed">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
```

Instead of having

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Active}"/>
```

I Would like to have something like

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource {Binding ExecutionState}}"/>
```

Thus if the state changes the text color changes. 
Is something like this even possible?
I can achieve the wanted functionality using triggers, but I have to reuse it at several places and I don't want to clutter my code.
I am using MVVM also.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty. StaticResource is not a DependencyObject, so there is no DependencyProperty. You should use Trigger(s) or develop your own attached behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve .
Create one attached property and assign the property name to bind.
In the property change callback function update control style.

```
<TextBlock  dep:CustomStyle.StyleName="{Binding ExecutionState}"    Text="Thiru"        />


public static  class CustomStyle
{
    static FrameworkPropertyMetadata _styleMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                     string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, StyleNamePropertyChangeCallBack);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StyleNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StyleName", typeof (String), typeof (CustomStyle), _styleMetadata);

    public static void SetStyleName(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(StyleNameProperty, value);
    }
    public static Boolean GetStyleName(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Boolean)element.GetValue(StyleNameProperty);
    }


    public static void StyleNamePropertyChangeCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        FrameworkElement ctrl = d as FrameworkElement;

        if (ctrl.IsLoaded)
        {

            string styleName = Convert.ToString(e.NewValue);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(styleName))
            {
                ctrl.Style = ctrl.TryFindResource(styleName) as Style;
            }
        }
    }
}
```